# show data select option by user in laravel

Tags: laravel, model, pivot-table, relationship, select-options

I want to show Project Data in select option by assign User login.

this my form select option

```
<div class="form-group">          
  <label for="">Project *</label>        
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="project_id">
      <option value="project_id" selected>Select One</option>
         @foreach($projects as $id => $project)
           <option value="{{$id}}">{{$project}}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

this my controller to pluck project name by assign user

```
$projects = UserProjects::pluck('project_id', 'user_id');
```

and I use `Many To Many Relation`.

in my User Model

```
public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::Class, 'user_projects');
    }
```

in my Project model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_projects');
}
```

and in my table pivot `user_projects` it just `project_id` and `user_id`. what should i write in my select option in form.?

Comment: Do you want to show all projects or just the ones that are already attached to the user?

Comment: only displays the project based on assign user. for example when entering as user A, then the select option only displays the list of projects done by use A

Answer (score 0):

In `many to many relation` you don't have to define a Model for the intermediate table (user_projects).

**Controller**

```
$user_projects = auth()->user()->projects;
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">          
  <label for="">Project *</label>        
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="project_id">
      <option value="project_id" selected>Select One</option>

      @foreach($user_projects as $user_project)
           <option value="{{$user_project->id}}">{{$user_project->name}}</option>
      @endforeach

    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: any errors `Cannot declare class App\Models\User, because the name is already in use`

Comment: What is that? Why are you creating a new `User Model`?